# HTML adding <em> and running Tidy2 adds unwanted space automatically

Tags: css, markup, tidy

Adding `<em>` and running Tidy2 adds a carriage return that adds an unwanted space.

No extra space:

```
<p>"The way ... etc.
```

It produces (what I want):

> "The way ... etc.

But when I add `<em>` (or `<b>`):

**EDIT 1:**
So markup looks like:

```
<p>"<em>The way ... etc.
```

AND after I run Notepad++ Tidy2 so my html looks like:

```
<p>" 
    <em>The way ... etc.
```

It produces and extra space after the quote mark (not what I want):

> " The way ... etc.

If I do not run Notepad++ Tidy2 or go back and remove the extra return added by Tidy2 after I add `<em>` or `<b>` it looks the way I want (without the extra space before the word "The"). I'd rather not do that 50 times every time I publish and run tidy2.

I'm not a hardcore markup guy. Just getting something done once in a while. Would rather not introduce an entire new dev environment etc. Tidy2 keeps me sane/organized quickly, love it...most of the time. I've tried modifying and removing Tidy2 config settings and tried all three config options. Happens in Chrome and Edge.

Stylesheet:

```
em {
    font-weight: 900;       
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

Tried adding this to the  style, didn't help:

```
    margin: 0px;
    content: "";
```

right-click inspect shows markup like this:

```
<p>
"" "
<em>...etc.
```

Tried using `&quot;`. Works just like the quote mark.

Using Notepad+++ v8.4.8.

Let me know what else you need. That's all I can think of.

**EDIT 2**:
I'm a former quantitative financial value and global macroeconomic analyst/researcher and former hedge fund CTO/CRO who programs when it is necessary and no one else can figure it out etc. Not very familiar with Tidy/Tidy2/Notepad++/or any dev environment or tools for that matter or there options beyond what I can find online.

Comment: It's not really clear what your markup looks like _before_ running `Tidy2`. Could you please [edit] your question to show both before and after?

Comment: The whitespace is created between the quotation mark and the inline HTML tags when the tags are put on a new line. I have not used Tidy2 or anything similar. Is there an option to have only block-level elements indented on a new line?

Comment: @Philisonstrike, see edit1

Comment: @TimR, see edit2

Comment: This has nothing related to Notepad++.

Comment: @Toto - recall, tidy2 is running in notepad plus plus and I don't know what the problem is or much about either of those. How can reasonably I know it's not notepad ++ causing it if I don't really know how it works? Kind of silly